# C# RSA encrypt then decrypt fails(error:0407A079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP:oaep decoding error)

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Encodings;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;


    public string RsaEncryptWithPublic(string clearText)
    {
        var bytesToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clearText);

        var encryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

        using (var txtreader = new StringReader(publickey))
        {
            var keyParameter = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)new PemReader(txtreader).ReadObject();

            encryptEngine.Init(true, keyParameter);
        }

        var encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytesToEncrypt, 0, bytesToEncrypt.Length));
        Console.WriteLine(encrypted);
        return encrypted;

    }
```

And my public key look like this:

```
public string publickey = @"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
";
```

Error when Server side decrypt (error:0407A079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP:oaep decoding error).

can i edit my code to accommodate server side?

can i encrypt using RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP:oaep decoding mathod?

Comment: Is that *actually* your key? Or did you obfuscate it for SO (And since it's a public key, you needn't obfuscate it anyway)?

Comment: no, i am just provide my key format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static string Encrypt(string data)
      {
          string _publicKey = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                                xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                                xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                                xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                                xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                                xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                                xxxxxxxx";
          RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = DecodeX509PublicKey(Convert.FromBase64String(_publicKey));
          return (Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data), true)));
      }

private static  bool CompareBytearrays(byte[] a, byte[] b)
      {
          if (a.Length != b.Length)
              return false;
          int i = 0;
          foreach (byte c in a)
          {
              if (c != b[i])
                  return false;
              i++;
          }
          return true;
      }

public static  RSACryptoServiceProvider DecodeX509PublicKey(byte[] x509key)
      {
          // encoded OID sequence for  PKCS #1 rsaEncryption szOID_RSA_RSA = "1.2.840.113549.1.1.1"
          byte[] SeqOID = { 0x30, 0x0D, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xF7, 0x0D, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00 };
          byte[] seq = new byte[15];
          // ---------  Set up stream to read the asn.1 encoded SubjectPublicKeyInfo blob  ------
          MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(x509key);
          BinaryReader binr = new BinaryReader(mem);    //wrap Memory Stream with BinaryReader for easy reading
          byte bt = 0;
          ushort twobytes = 0;

          try
          {

              twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
              if (twobytes == 0x8130) //data read as little endian order (actual data order for Sequence is 30 81)
                  binr.ReadByte();    //advance 1 byte
              else if (twobytes == 0x8230)
                  binr.ReadInt16();   //advance 2 bytes
              else
                  return null;

              seq = binr.ReadBytes(15);       //read the Sequence OID
              if (!CompareBytearrays(seq, SeqOID))    //make sure Sequence for OID is correct
                  return null;

              twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
              if (twobytes == 0x8103) //data read as little endian order (actual data order for Bit String is 03 81)
                  binr.ReadByte();    //advance 1 byte
              else if (twobytes == 0x8203)
                  binr.ReadInt16();   //advance 2 bytes
              else
                  return null;

              bt = binr.ReadByte();
              if (bt != 0x00)     //expect null byte next
                  return null;

              twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
              if (twobytes == 0x8130) //data read as little endian order (actual data order for Sequence is 30 81)
                  binr.ReadByte();    //advance 1 byte
              else if (twobytes == 0x8230)
                  binr.ReadInt16();   //advance 2 bytes
              else
                  return null;

              twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
              byte lowbyte = 0x00;
              byte highbyte = 0x00;

              if (twobytes == 0x8102) //data read as little endian order (actual data order for Integer is 02 81)
                  lowbyte = binr.ReadByte();  // read next bytes which is bytes in modulus
              else if (twobytes == 0x8202)
              {
                  highbyte = binr.ReadByte(); //advance 2 bytes
                  lowbyte = binr.ReadByte();
              }
              else
                  return null;
              byte[] modint = { lowbyte, highbyte, 0x00, 0x00 };   //reverse byte order since asn.1 key uses big endian order
              int modsize = BitConverter.ToInt32(modint, 0);

              byte firstbyte = binr.ReadByte();
              binr.BaseStream.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.Current);

              if (firstbyte == 0x00)
              {   //if first byte (highest order) of modulus is zero, don't include it
                  binr.ReadByte();    //skip this null byte
                  modsize -= 1;   //reduce modulus buffer size by 1
              }

              byte[] modulus = binr.ReadBytes(modsize);   //read the modulus bytes

              if (binr.ReadByte() != 0x02)            //expect an Integer for the exponent data
                  return null;
              int expbytes = (int)binr.ReadByte();        // should only need one byte for actual exponent data (for all useful values)
              byte[] exponent = binr.ReadBytes(expbytes);

              // ------- create RSACryptoServiceProvider instance and initialize with public key -----
              RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
              RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = new RSAParameters();
              RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = modulus;
              RSAKeyInfo.Exponent = exponent;
              RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
              return RSA;
          }
          catch (Exception)
          {
              return null;
          }

          finally { binr.Close(); }

      }
```